# Android view.playSoundEffect plays multiple times

Tags: android, onclicklistener, playsound

So I have an onClickListener to start a timer. I added the code to play the android "click" sound, but sometimes when the view is pressed the sound is played multiple times as a "click-click". The information generated by the click event is saved to a file and I am not recieving evidence of multiple clicks there, but am definitely hearing it audibly.I moved the sound within my if statements, and this remedied the issue slightly, but there is still some multi-clicks. It seems they generally happen when pressing with the pad of my finger versus the tip.

```
public OnClickListener lapListener = new OnClickListener() 
{    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

       //if new timer = 0 the timer is not running. Start the clock, and make necessary changes
       if(newTimer == 0)
       {
           view.playSoundEffect(android.view.SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
            customHandler.postDelayed(updateLapThread, 0);
            newTimer = 1;
            running = 1;
            stopButton.setText("Stop"); 
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
       }
       //if newtimer = 1 and running = 1 the timer is going and the user wishes to end the current lap
       else if (newTimer == 1 && running == 1)
       {

           view.playSoundEffect(android.view.SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
           customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateLapThread);
           finishLap();
           customHandler.postDelayed(updateLapThread, 5000);


       }
       else
       {
             //Do nothing   
       }


   }
};
```